# Efficient way of finding average difference between elements in array

Tags: matlab

Hope title isn't confusing.  It's simple to show by example.  I have a row vector like so: `[1 5 6]`.  I want to find the average difference between each element.  The differences in this example are 4 and 1 so the average is 2.5.  This is a small example.  My row vectors might be very large.  I'm new to MatLab so is there some efficient way of using MATLAB's efficient matrix/array manipulation to do this nicely?

There is a similar question on SOF already but this question is specifically for MATLAB!

Thanks :)

EDIT: As queried by @gnovice, I wanted the absolute difference.

Comment: I knew this would be a popular question :)!.  Thanks guys.

Comment: One small question: Do you care about the *sign* of the differences? In other words, do you want to take the *absolute value* of the differences? With a vector like `[1 5 1]`, the mean of the differences is 0, but the mean of the absolute value of the differences is 4.

Comment: Hey gnovice.  What I actually did is `mean(abs(diff(myVector)));` (variation of solution by @Azim) because yes, I wanted the absolute difference.  I should have told everyone this so thanks for bringing it up.  I will edit my question :).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple solution using *diff* and *mean*

```
aveDiff = mean(diff(myVector))     %#(1)
```

Example

```
>> v=[1 5 6]
v =
     1     5     6
>> mean(diff(v))
ans =
    2.5000
```

This works but @Jonas' answer is the correct solution.

---

***Edit***

From @gnovice, @vivid-colours and @sevenless comments.

The mean of the absolute value of the difference can be found by inserting *abs* into (1)

```
aveDiff = mean(abs(diff(myVector)))     %#(2)
```

Comment: You could add the absolute value function to fix it.  That is, aveDiff = mean(abs(diff(myVector))).

Answer (score 5):

If you have an array `array`, then the average difference is

```
(array(end) - array(1))/(length(array)-1)
```

because `diff(array)`, where `array = [a b c d]`, is `[b-a c-b d-c]`. The average of that is `(b-a+c-b+d-c)/3`, which simplifies to `(d-a)/3`.

In your example

```
array = [1 5 6];

(array(end)-array(1))/2 

ans =
2.5
```

Comment: It's a nice efficient solution, but won't work if you want the mean of the *absolute values* of the differences (an additional requirement now edited into the question).

Answer (score 0):

If X is your vector, you can do

```
mean( X(2:end) - X(1:end-1) )
```