# Efficient way to calculate average time between row dates grouped by ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, group-by, average

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
thedate                   ID 
2014-10-20 14:13:42.063   1
2014-10-20 14:13:43.063   1
2014-10-20 14:13:47.063   1
2014-10-20 14:12:50.063   2
2014-10-20 14:13:49.063   2
2014-10-20 14:13:54.063   2
2014-10-20 14:20:24.063   2
2014-10-20 14:13:02.063   3
```

To replicate a similar toybox table as in this example you can use the following code:

```
declare @tmp as table(thedate datetime,ID int)
insert into @tmp (thedate, ID) values
    (dateadd(s,0,getdate()),1), (dateadd(s,1,getdate()),1), (dateadd(s,5,getdate()),1),
     (dateadd(s,-52,getdate()),2), (dateadd(s,7,getdate()),2), (dateadd(s,12,getdate()),2),(dateadd(s,402,getdate()),2),
     (dateadd(s,-40,getdate()),3)
```

For each ID I want the average time between the dates. Now the database is huge (lots of ID's and dates for each ID), so it has to be very efficient. I want a result like this:

```
ID  AvgTime (seconds)
 1  2,5
 2  151,333333333333
 3  NULL
```

The following code does what I want, but it is way too slow:

```
select
   a.ID,
   (select top 1 avg(cast(datediff(s,(select max(thedate) 
                                         from @tmp c where ID = b.ID 
                                             and thedate < b.thedate)
                                     ,thedate) as float)) over (partition by b.ID)
       from @tmp b where ID = a.ID)
from @tmp a group by ID
```

Does anyone know how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average is the maximum minus the minimum divided by one less than the count.  You can use this to write a relatively simple query:

```
select id,
       cast(datediff(second, min(thedate), max(thedate)) as float) / (count(*) - 1)
from @tmp
group by id;
```

If some of the ids only have one row, then you'll want to check for potential divide by 0:

```
select id,
       (case when count(*) > 1
             then cast(datediff(second, min(thedate), max(thedate)) as float) / (count(*) - 1)
        end) as AvgDiff
from @tmp
group by id;
```

Comment: It's instructive to see why this works -- without repeating it here, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5160040/4137916) on a closely related question.

Comment: Very much appriciated - Thank you!